# Undefined class constant 'ATTR_ERROR_MODE with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wanted to insert data into a database using PDO:

```
   $ServerName='localhost';
   $UserName='root';
   $DbName='scholar';
   $Password='';
   try{

   $conn=new PDO("mysql::host=$ServerName,dbname=$DbName",$UserName,$Password);
 //set the PDO error mode to exception
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERROR_MODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $sql="INSERT INTO register(id,first,Last,Father,email,gender,phone,category,current,class10,class12,diploma,bachelor,course,poly,btech,leet,time/date)".
         "VALUES('','$first','$last','$Father','$email','$gender','$phone','$category',"
         ."'$current','$class10','$class12','$diploma','$bachelor','$course','$poly','$btech','$leet','$date')";
   $conn->exec($sql);
   echo'record added successfully';

   }  catch(PDOException $e){
     echo $sql."<br>".$e->getMessage();
   $conn=null;  
 }
```

But then this error occurred, and I can't fix it:

> error: Undefined class constant 'ATTR_ERROR_MODE'

Answer (score 4):

Correct the constant

From

```
PDO::ATTR_ERROR_MODE
```

To

```
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE
```

Read [PDO::setAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Comment: see http://docs.php.net/pdo.constants#pdo.constants.attr-errmode  and/or http://docs.php.net/pdo.error-handling (really? for days?)